# How to get One to Many Room Android With condition on BOTH table?

Tags: android, android-sqlite, android-room

I have a table User and Pet:

```
public class User{
    String id;
    String name;
    String age;
}
```

```
public class Pet{
    String id;
    String userId;
    String name;
    String age;
}
```

```
@Query("SELECT u.* ," +
            "p.id p_id," +
            "p.name p_name " +
            "p.age p_age " +
            "FROM user u LEFT JOIN pet p ON u.id=p.userId WHERE u.age= :userAge AND p.age = :petAge")
    public UserAndPet getOldUserAndOldPet(int userAge, int petAge);
```

My Model

```
public class UserAndPet{

    @Embedded
    User user;

    @Embedded(prefix = "p_")
    List<Pet> pets;
}
```

1 Users can have Many Pets.

The Question is:
The model not working, when I search why, some say List can't be embedded.
I can't find any problem like this, and I wonder how can everyone in this world never face this problem? This is very common, One to Many Relationship with conditions on both table.

Every question and answer I met is using `@Relation`

```
public class UserAndPet{

    @Embedded
    User user;

    @Relation(
            parentColumn = "id",
            entityColumn = "userId"
    )
    List<Pet> pets;
}
```

Yes it can be done IF THERE IS NO CONDITION

Thank you